# "unknown file system" error in fstab when trying to mount a cifs share

Tags: samba, fstab

Anyone have an idea why a cifs mounted share suddenly doesn't work in fstab? I can mount it from the command line, but `mount -a` gives:

> unknown file system '-o'.

I had a bit of trouble getting it to work a few weeks ago, but after some research I figured out the line that I needed.

```
//10.x.x.x/shared /mnt/shared -o credentials=/etc/cifspwd,rw,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777 0 0
```

Then after updating last week and rebooting the server, it wouldn't mount and I had to "skip" it. As I mentioned, I can mount it manually, but not via fstab.

I'm running server 12.04

Answer (score 1):

Don't put `-o` in fstab. The fourth field is the options that will be passed to `mount`. And you're missing the filesystem type. The line should be like this:

```
//10.x.x.x/shared /mnt/shared cifs credentials=/etc/cifspwd,rw,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777 0 0
```

See also: [fstab manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/fstab.5.html).

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I wonder why it worked prior to the update.